# Why would gcc -O3 generate multiple ret instructions?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, micro-optimization

I was looking at some recursive function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700102/584518):

```
int get_steps_to_zero(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        // Base case: we have reached zero
        return 0;
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        // Recursive case 1: we can divide by 2
        return 1 + get_steps_to_zero(n / 2);
    } else {
        // Recursive case 2: we can subtract by 1
        return 1 + get_steps_to_zero(n - 1);
    }
}
```

I checked the disassembly in order to check if gcc managed tail-call optimization/unrolling. Looks like it did, though with x86-64 gcc 12.2 -O3 I get a function like this, ending with two `ret` instructions:

```
get_steps_to_zero:
        xor     eax, eax
        test    edi, edi
        jne     .L5
        jmp     .L6
.L10:
        mov     edx, edi
        shr     edx, 31
        add     edi, edx
        sar     edi
        test    edi, edi
        je      .L9
.L5:
        add     eax, 1
        test    dil, 1
        je      .L10
        sub     edi, 1
        test    edi, edi
        jne     .L5
.L9:
        ret
.L6:
        ret
```

[Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/qG6rK86PY).

What's the purpose of the multiple returns? Is it a bug?

---

EDIT

Seems like this appeared from gcc 11.x. When compiling under gcc 10.x, then the function ends like:

```
.L1:
        mov     eax, r8d
        ret
.L6:
        xor     r8d, r8d
        mov     eax, r8d
        ret
```

As in: store result in `eax`. The 11.x version instead zeroes `eax` in the beginning of the function then modifies it in the function body, eliminating the need for the extra `mov` instruction.

Comment: Looks like a missed optimisation to me.  Another possible reason is that the two `ret` instructions correspond to different source lines.  Keeping them separate might permit more precise debugging information.

Comment: @fuz If so then why not 3 `ret` corresponding to the 3 `return` in the original C source?

Comment: I don't know, I have not seen your original code as you had not added it to your question.

Comment: @fuz Added. I also found out that this seems to be because of some optimization introduced in gcc 11.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why does GCC emit a repeated `ret`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62556736/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Not so sure about that. That question is from 2020, gcc 11 was released 2021 after which the behavior changed.

Comment: I have posted an answer that addresses your question specifically, and the reason in the linked question is the same. Are you satisfied with my explanation?

Comment: @amonakov I came to the same conclusion in the edit above where I compiled with an older gcc. One label would set eax to zero there too. I was mostly curious about why, since the code from my edit could as well just have set the L1 label at the second `mov     eax, r8d` row. But apparently this is a known bug.

Comment: Can you mark my  answer is accepted then?

Comment: @amonakov I believe the answer in the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557809/584518 answers the question

Answer (score 3):

This is a manifestation of pass ordering problem. At some point in the optimization pipeline, the two basic blocks ending in `ret` are not equivalent, then some pass makes them equivalent, but no following pass is capable of collapsing the two equivalent blocks into one.

On Compiler Explorer, you can see how compiler optimization pipeline works by inspecting snapshots of internal representation between passes. For GCC, select "Add New > GCC Tree/RTL" in the compiler pane. Here's your example, with a snapshot immediately preceding the problematic transformation pre-selected in the new pane: https://godbolt.org/z/nTazM5zGG

Towards the end of the dump, you can see the two basic blocks:

```
   65: NOTE_INSN_BASIC_BLOCK 8
   77: use ax:SI
   66: simple_return
```

and

```
  43: NOTE_INSN_BASIC_BLOCK 9
    5: ax:SI=0
   38: use ax:SI
   74: NOTE_INSN_EPILOGUE_BEG
   75: simple_return
```

Basically the second block is different in that it sets `eax` to zero before returning. If you look at the next pass (called "jump2"), you see that it lifts the `ax:SI=0` instruction from basic block 9 and basic block 3 to basic block 2, making BB 9 equivalent to BB 8.

If you disable this optimization with `-fno-crossjumping`, the difference will be carried to the end, making the resulting assembly less surprising.

Answer (score -2):

Conclusion first: This is a deliberate optimization choice by GCC.

If you use GCC locally (`gcc -O3 -S`) instead of on Godbolt, you can see that there are [alignment directives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21546946/5958455) between the two `ret` instructions:

```
; top part omitted
.L9:
        ret
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L6:
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

The object file, when disassembled, includes an NOP in that padding area:

```
   8:   75 13                   jne    1d <get_steps_to_zero+0x1d>
   a:   eb 24                   jmp    30 <get_steps_to_zero+0x30>
   c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
<...>
  2b:   75 f0                   jne    1d <get_steps_to_zero+0x1d>
  2d:   c3                      ret
  2e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  30:   c3                      ret
```

The second `ret` instruction is aligned to a 16-byte boundary whereas the first one isn't. This allows the processor to load the instruction faster when used as a jump target from a distant source. Subsequent C `return` statements, however, are close enough to the first `ret` instruction such that they will not benefit from jumping to aligned targets.

This alignment is even more noticeable on my Zen 2 CPU with `-mtune=native`, with more padding bytes added:

```
  29:   75 f2                   jne    1d <get_steps_to_zero+0x1d>
  2b:   c3                      ret
  2c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  30:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: `ret` is 1 byte long, and unconditionally jumps.  It's not useful to load later instruction bytes after it, and any code-fetch of any chunk that includes it will get the whole instruction.  There's no benefit to having it be aligned.  Also, if this reasoning were true, we'd expect the earlier `jmp .L6` to also target the "aligned" `ret`, with the unaligned one only reached via fall-through.

Comment: @PeterCordes `.L6` *is* the aligned `ret`. Assuming you meant the other way, it's because the `jmp .L9` instruction is close enough (<16 bytes) to the unaligned `ret` such that it will have been loaded by the time `jmp` enters the execution stage, so there's no need to load a more distant one only to serve as the jump target.

Comment: Well if you compile the godbolt example I posted to binary it inserts `xchg   ax,ax` between the `ret` which iirc is Intelese for "nop". Also it ends with these two lines `cs nop WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]`, `nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]`.

Comment: But I don't understand why alignment would be an argument for having two `ret` anyway. If there was a need for such you would just use one `ret` and pad everything else with `nop`.

Comment: Yes, I got that backwards, you're correct about what I meant to say.  Interesting hypothesis about being within 16 bytes.  I don't think GCC actually counts bytes, though; it just prints asm text without knowing the length in bytes.  That's part of why [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646) is only via an assembler option, not a compiler option.  Also, jumping into a 16-byte chunk that's already in the pipeline doesn't actually help, AFAIK, except insofar as it means those bytes are definitely hot in I-cache.

Comment: Still, it's *possible* GCC devs had the same within-16-bytes idea and wrote code to do it this way on purpose, even though I don't think it's helpful on real CPUs.  More likely I think it's just a missed optimization.  Or left over from some CPUs where it maybe helped branch prediction to have different paths out of the function use a different `ret` instruction?  Unlikely, since call/ret prediction is normally handled via special predictors.  I'm pretty sure this is just a missed optimization, though.

Comment: If anyone's familiar enough with GCC internals, we could confirm this answer by finding the code inside GCC which checks for jump target range and invents a new aligned epilogue block if it's farther than 16 bytes.  But it's hard to prove a negative this way; there's a *lot* of code to dig through to prove that no such code exists.

Comment: @PeterCordes Another (wild) guess is GCC not optimizing across basic blocks in the lowest-level IR.

Comment: @iBug: Yeah, that was my guess.  That it doesn't check for them being the same after whatever step made them the same, only at some earlier point where they returned different source variables, perhaps in different registers.  Perhaps only looking in the GIMPLE, or too early in RTL.  This is a common missed optimization for GCC.  I guess another way to rule out the within-16-byte hypothesis would be to find a case where different more-distant branches also target redundant tail blocks.

Comment: @PeterCordes Still doesn't explain gcc behavior up to version 10.x.x, see edit of the question. Or check this https://godbolt.org/z/48dPjv9Pf.  Why didn't they just skip the part below L1 and move the L1 label to the final `mov     eax, r8d`? It's the same strange code just a different flavour of it. I think part of the answer to the question lies in some changes in code generation/optimization in version 11.x.x.